# I want to apply validations depending upon the condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "**", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Only 10 Numbers Allowed......")]
    [RegularExpression("[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}", ErrorMessage = "Must Be In AAAAA1234A format")]
    [Display(Name = "PAN No:")]
    public string PANNo { get; set;}
```

This is the property defined in the model(class Company Master). I want to apply the validation according to the specific conditions e.g. If I select Company from the dropdown list, then the fourth letter of the PAN no must be "C" or if I select Firm , then it should be "F" also the fifth letter must be the First letter of the Surname(lastname). how can I do it????

Comment: Did you try anything? Have a look at [ask] and share a [MCVE]!

Comment: Paste the code snippet that you have tried.

Comment: Consider using FluentValidations NuGet package - https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation. This will provide you much more control over your validations, and you can achieve conditional validations quite easily and efficiently.